# Ignoring objects on NSArray - Memory Manager

Tags: ios, xcode

What I am trying to do is to ignore all objects from a array and point it to another set of objects. Something like that:

```
[myArrayFullOfObjects removeAllObjects];
myArrayFullOfObjects = nil;
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];
myArrayFullOfObjects = newArray;
```

Is it correct? I want to avoid memory leaks with the old objects "myArrayFullOfObjects" was pointing to.

Comment: it depends on if you're using Auto Reference Counting (ARC) or not. if not, you're leaking.

Answer (score 7):

On your code this line:

```
myArrayFullOfObjects = nil;
```

will cause the memory leak, because you will no longer have a pointer to that array, and therefore it will never be released, so you can either do this:

```
[myArrayFullOfObjects release];
myArrayFullOfObjects = nil;
```

or

You can just declare your newArray as a property like this:

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *newArray;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize newArray;
```

and then simply do:

```
self.newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];

//Note that arrayWithObjects returns and autoreleased object, however the property setter will send it a retain message, so it will end up with a retain count of 1.
```

As bshirley mentions, this is if you are not using ARC, if you are using ARC you don't really have to worry about this.

The generated setter, will release the previous value, so that no memory leaks occur.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! What if I simply remove the line: myArrayFullOfObjects = nil from the code? When I do: myArrayFullOfObjects = newArray, the memory area where myArrayFullOfObjects was pointing to before will become a leak?